# Using when() inside a for loop in kotlin. The lines below the when statement are not executed

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am coding in Kotlin in an Android project. I am using a when() statement inside a for() loop. There are some lines below the when() statement that needs to be executed in each iteration of the loop, but is skipped and the control flows back to the next iteration of the loop.

This is a simplified version of what I do.

```
    for (i : Int in 0..10)
    {
        val data = Data()

        when(i)
        {
            0 -> data.att1 = "sample0"
            1 -> data.att1 = "sample1"
            2 -> data.att1 = "sample2"
            ..
            ..
        }

        dataArray.add(i, data) // LINE NOT EXECUTED
    }
```

I am kind of new to Kotlin, so I am not sure if this is normal behaviour in Kotlin. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. The code should be executed.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: You need to show us more code. The code you're showing [works](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/v0mtep47t07g7hapqem62emjci/ehapco2v95n4lcaibkg2uof74v)

Comment: Tested it again. The problem seems to be with the debugger. The debugger skips the lines below the when() but is actually executed. Even the breakpoint placed below the when() is shown as not executable. Sorry to have wasted all of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the Android Studio Debugger. The lines below when() block were skipped while debugging but were actually executed.

The break pint placed there also displayed error stating that "No executable code is present in that line"

Answer (score -1):

After your when add an else statement

```
   When(I){

    0-> ...
    1-> ....
    } else {
    Log.i(TAG, “error”)
    }
```

Kotlin when expressions require an else

Comment: Kotlin does not REQUIRE an `else` inside a `when`.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html

Comment: I didn’t say inside the when. Reading the documentation it says when used as a statement it doesn’t. If it is an expression it does require an else to FOLLOW it. We can’t see all of his code. It is the best guess I can make with the given information.

Comment: Where do the docs say you can follow a `when` with `else`? *If when is used as an expression, the else branch is mandatory, unless the compiler can prove that all possible cases are covered with branch conditions.* The branch is within `when`, not after it, and is not always required for the expression usage.

Comment: Ok you got me on the inside part. But it is not required if every possible option is covered. If every possible option were covered then wouldn’t it then complete? He is iterating through a range. ..... actually I have a compiler on my other phone I wanna try it

Comment: Yes, whatever is in the `..`s of the OP's code, the only way it's going to skip to the next iteration is if one has a `continue`.